# Doing actions and delays on transporters in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyowP.jpg)
I am trying to build a model represented as shown but, i had problems with the transporters. First, i wanted to make a queue and delay before reaching loading point but when i ran the model i had an error as i tried to cast the delay and the queue to my transporter agent (forklift) and not the material item type , and whe i tried to cast it to my agent (material item type) it didn't respond or see the delay or the queue and the transporter didn't stop.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXHh1.jpg)
After loading i want to make a second stop (delay) and queue of transporters out side it , the model only see the delay and (loaded transporters) ran through the queue and stop in the delay block and i want to investigate the queue but the transports didn't stop in it. How i can put my hands on transporters and can do sequence logic on them while been loaded and unloaded along the path.
[some irregularities in changing colors due to condition] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORr9E.jpg
[resource pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpW7c.jpg)
finally, when i tried to change the color of my resource(cranes) according to seize and release in resource
pool but, i got a few irregularities in changing the color according to the state.
thanx for the help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. You actually ask *several* questions at once. Please split these into several, separate questions. This helps you and others in the future with similar problems. Some more tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, happy to help

Comment: thanx Benjamin for your response i will separate my questions.